# Possible to apply TransportWithMessageCredential only sometimes?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that is defined as follows:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyNamespace.MyUserNamePasswordValidator, MyAssembly" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom" serviceAuthorizationManagerType="MyNamespace.MyServiceAuthorizationManager, MyAssembly">
        <authorizationPolicies>
          <add policyType="MyNamespace.MyAuthorizationPolicy, MyAssembly" />
        </authorizationPolicies>
      </serviceAuthorization>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyServiceBinding">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="MyNamespace.Service" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" contract="MyNamespace.Service" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServiceBinding" />
  </service>
</services>
```

This uses `TransportWithMessageCredential` to require that every service operation request has a username/password combination supplied. However, there is a single operation that users of the service need to be able to access without providing credentials, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to implement this functionality.

We have a custom username and password validator, as well as a custom authorization policy, but none of the methods on those classes get hit when a username or password isn't supplied in the credentials header; the server immediately returns an error 500 fault with the text "An error occurred when verifying security for the message".

Is it possible to have a "most but not all" approach when using `TransportWithMessageCredential`, and if so, where should I look to implement this?

Comment: I believe the normal way of dealing with scenarios like yours is to have a separate endpoint for the insecure operations.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Unfortunately not possible due to business requirements.